# Querying all views in SQL Server 2012 database instance

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am having a problem where the query below is only selecting the views from the current database I am connected to and not all.  Is there anyway to do this and not use `sp_MSForEachDB`?

```
DECLARE @useText VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @viewNM VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @schemaNM VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @dbNM VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @sqlCmd varchar(4000)

DECLARE DBCursor CURSOR GLOBAL FOR
  SELECT NAME FROM SYS.DATABASES

OPEN DBCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor INTO @dbNM

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    SET @useText = 'USE [' + @dbNM + ']'
    EXEC(@useText)

    DECLARE ViewCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' +  name + ']' + ' TO [account]'
        FROM SYS.VIEWS V

    OPEN ViewCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM ViewCursor INTO @sqlCmd

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
         PRINT(@sqlCmd)
         FETCH NEXT FROM ViewCursor INTO @sqlCmd
    END

    CLOSE ViewCursor
    DEALLOCATE ViewCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor INTO @dbNM
END

CLOSE DBCursor
DEALLOCATE DBCursor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `EXEC` statement executes a string, the string is executed as its own self-contained batch. So, the `USE dbname` does not affect the query outside of the `EXEC`.

I build a query statement like this, `SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' +  name + '] TO [account]' FROM [master].SYS.VIEWS V;` where the database name is inserted before the SYS.VIEWS.

See below:

```
DECLARE @useText VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @viewNM VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @schemaNM VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @dbNM VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @sqlCmd varchar(4000)

DECLARE DBCursor CURSOR GLOBAL FOR
  SELECT NAME FROM SYS.DATABASES

OPEN DBCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor INTO @dbNM

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN

        set @sqlCmd = 'SELECT ''GRANT SELECT ON ['' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + ''].['' +  name + ''] TO [account]'' FROM [' + @dbNM + '].SYS.VIEWS V;'

        exec( @sqlCmd );

    FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor INTO @dbNM
END

CLOSE DBCursor
DEALLOCATE DBCursor
```

**EDIT:**

You could append a `USE` in front of the `GRANT`.

```
set @sqlCmd = 'SELECT ''USE ' + @dbNM + '; GRANT SELECT ON ['' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + ''].['' +  name + ''] TO [account]'' FROM [' + @dbNM + '].SYS.VIEWS V;'
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think you may have another issue with the GRANT. You can only grant or revoke permissions on objects in the current database.